# Nicest way to render different partials on a rails object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a list of videos which i show in different ways.
If I was only displaying it in one way, I would simply write

```
<% videos.each do |video| %>
<%= render video %>
<% end %>
```

This loads my `_video.html.erb` partial, but sometimes I'd like to load a different partial, depending on my view.

What's the most "Rails way" of having multiple views to render depending on the page it's being listed?

So on my home page I can render `_video.html.erb`, but on another page I could render `_video_list.html.erb`. Right now I'm just calling the method

```
<%= render 'videos/video_list' locals: video %>
```

But I get the feeling there's a nicer way? I feel like it would be great if I could write

```
<%= render video, 'list' %>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging, it looks like this is the best way

```
<%= render video, list: true %>


_video.html.erb

<% if local_assigns[:list] %>
#list view
<% elsif local_assigns[:select] %>
#select view
<% else %>
#default view
<% end %>
```

This actually feels pretty nice. Do I'll mark it as correct in a few days if no one can suggest something that might be better?

Thanks

Comment: I would advise against this. This kind of partials become quickly a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @tompave so what do you suggest in place of if elsif else?

Comment: If you want to do this and the view gets to complex, you can create specialized view files like `_video_list.html.erb`,  `_video_select.html.erb` and `_video_default.html.erb` and use `_video.html.erb` just for the if-elsif-elsif checks and render the specialized files with explicit `render partial: '...'` calls. Conceptually this would be the same solution as @shmargum's answer, but with the condition pulled out of `to_partial_path` into the view.

Answer (score 3):

To have the same model render different templates based on some condition, you can implement the `to_partial_path` method on any object and call render on that object:

```
def to_partial_path
  if list?
    "videos/list"
  else
    "videos"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a collection of videos, you can use

```
<%= render videos %>
```

instead of

```
<% videos.each do |video| %>
  <%= render video %>
<% end %>
```

To render a different a partial `views/videos/_list.html.erb` from another file in `views/videos`, you can do this:

```
<%= render 'list', video: @video %>
```

The hash argument on the end makes the instance variable `@video` available in the `list` partial is a local variable called `video`. You could technically access `@videos` in the `list` partial directly, but its easier to keep track of things if you pass in a new variable explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I'm just calling the method
>   `<%= render 'videos/video_list' locals: video %>`

That shouldn't work.

It's either:
`<%= render 'videos/video_list', video: video %>`
or:
`<%= render partial: 'videos/video_list', locals: { video: video } %>`

Either is definitely more correct, explicit, simple and resilient than any "clever" automagic helper.